# Do NATs usually let packets enter local network if they are sent to an already active port, but from different address?

Tags: nat

I am a newbie so I am sorry if this is a dumb question. In that case please hint me where to start reading so I can answer my own qestions.

So, I have two clients and a server. Both clients establish a connection to the server. Server then sends complete addresses (both IP and port) of both of the clients to both of them. Now clients start listening on the same ports and they start sending packets to each other's address. Will they be able to connect to each other?

This question, from my perspective, boils to that of whether ISPs' NATs have the habit to let packets pass only if they come to a known port, even if it comes from a completely new address?

Answer (score 0):

Basically no.
SNAT only passes connection in one direction, for the two clients to communicate one of them will need to have DNAT setup to be able to answer the call from the other client.

look into UPNP.

Comment: UPnP is unrelated thing. It permits devices behind NAT to create a port forward on the NAT gateway suitable for running arbitrary servers. While it can be used to simulate NAT traversal for p2p purposes, it was designed for other uses in mind. The O.P. mentioned only a *pair* of peers, while UPnP will generally allow *anyone* to connect to forwarded port and reach the machine behind NAT, and this makes big difference in security.

Answer (score 0):

No, such a simple scenario like you presented won't work. NATs store the remote address, remote port and local (translated) port, and will only translate back packets where all three fields match.

Basically the technologies like you described are commonly known under the umbrella term NAT [**hole punching**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)).

There are specific protocols that do this; most common one is [`STUN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), however, some  software include custom implementations of hole punching (`tinc` VPN comes into mind).